# Multiple HTTP GETs in one go on ESP8266

Tags: html, ajax, arduino, esp8266

I can't figure out how to send the data in one go. I am asking because sending it simultaneously delays a bit.

I did see an other topic of someone posting a piece of code, but that did not work.

This is a bit of the code:

```
void handleRoot() {
  String s = MAIN_page; // Read HTML contents
  server.send(200, "text/html", s); // Send web page
}
    
void handleFORESTTEMPERATURE() {
  String ForrestTemperatureDev =  String(ForestTemperature, 1);
     
  server.send(200, "text/plane", ForestTemperatureDev); // Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}
    
void handleFORESTPRESSURE() {
  String ForrestPressureDev = String(ForestPressure);
     
  server.send(200, "text/plane", ForrestPressureDev); // Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}
    
void handleFORESTHUMIDITY() {
  String ForrestHumidityDev = String(ForestHumidity);
     
  server.send(200, "text/plane", ForestHumidityDev); // Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

server.on("/readFORESTPRESSURE", handleFORESTPRESSURE);
server.on("/readFORESTTEMPERATURE", handleFORESTTEMPERATURE);
server.on("/readFORESTHUMIDITY", handleFORESTHUMIDITY);
server.on("/readFORESTWEATHERSTATUS", handleFORESTWEATHERSTATUS);
```

Comment: something like this https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/8b662ed3b345d2ded3c2ac484949b03e10bdc43c/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/Graph/Graph.ino#L222 ?

Comment: @Juraj yes exactly like that, how can i do it with the above info? can u show me. as im still learning. regards and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would send all three values separated with a `;` when `\readALL` is requested.

The three values can be split on the `;` in your receiving application; using JSON would be just a little bit more work.

Note1: Untested, I just typed it in, but you get the idea.

Note2: It's `text/plain`, not `text/plane`.

```cpp
void handleRoot() {
  String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
  server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}

void handleFORESTTEMPERATURE() {
  String ForrestTemperatureDev =  String(ForestTemperature, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", ForestTemperatureDev); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

void handleFORESTPRESSURE() {
  String ForrestPressureDev = String(ForestPressure);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", ForrestPressureDev); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

void handleFORESTHUMIDITY() {
  String ForrestHumidityDev = String(ForestHumidity);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", ForestHumidityDev); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

void handleALL() {
  String AllDev = String(ForestTemperature, 1) + ";" + String(ForestPressure) + ";" + String(ForestHumidity);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", AllDev); //Send ADC values only to client ajax request
}

server.on("/readFORESTPRESSURE", handleFORESTPRESSURE);
server.on("/readFORESTTEMPERATURE", handleFORESTTEMPERATURE);
server.on("/readFORESTHUMIDITY", handleFORESTHUMIDITY);
server.on("/readFORESTWEATHERSTATUS", handleFORESTWEATHERSTATUS);
server.on("/readALL", handleALL);
```

Comment: thanks!! now i need to see how to handle it on my html page. i will open another question soon.  thanks

Comment: because right now i don't know what value is what device. so i don't know if it's possible iin an other way?. because i use live status on my page and aswell button thats shows a value when pressed.  right now i call the devices like this on the html page, getData('UVFOREST', 'readFORESTUV');.

Comment: The values from handleAll will always arrive in the same order in one string on the webpage, like so: "temp;pres;hum". Put that in Javascript into a string str, and then do: var values = str.split(";"); then values[0] will be temperature, values[1] will be pressure, values[2] will be humidity.

Comment: thanks, well i try it, im still learning.  i know what u mean but can u show me a script example so i can start learning. regards

Comment: i found it out, var input = "10;11;15";
var arr = input.split(";");
alert(arr[1]);